# Window-list color

Tags: gnome-shell

Do anybody know how to change the background color of the items in the window-list and workspace overview? The items are placed on the panel at the bottom of my screen. I would like to change all the black background color to something lighter.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and I have tried to find where this color is defined in different CSS-files in /usr/share/gnome-shell/ and in /usr/share/themes/. But my search has been in vane.
Thanks in advance.